# c#: DI and additional parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, parameters, constructor, parameter-passing

For example, I have a class `CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService` with the following dependencies:

```
    protected readonly IDeviceService _deviceService;
    protected readonly IAzureFunctionLogService _azureFunctionLogService;
    protected readonly IDeviceValidationService _deviceValidationService;
```

so, I can create ctor for the class:

```
    public CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService(
        IDeviceService deviceService,
        IDeviceValidationService deviceValidationService,
        IAzureFunctionLogService azureFunctionLogService)
    {
        _deviceService = deviceService;
        _deviceValidationService = deviceValidationService;
        _azureFunctionLogService = azureFunctionLogService;
    }
```

then inject all dependencies like:

```
services.AddTransient<CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService>();
               services.AddSingleton<Func<CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService>>(sp =>
                   () => sp.GetRequiredService<CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService>()
               );
```

and then use it like this:

```
    private readonly Func<CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService> _service;


        public FunctionDebugPendingStatusWorkflow(
Func<CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService> service,
            //....
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _service = service;
            //....
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FunctionDebugPendingStatusWorkflow>();
        }
```

so, it works fine.

But how can I add one more param to ctor, which set in caller? For example, I want to pass `deviceId` to ctor and can't describe it as dependency using dependency injector in `Program.cs` (in my case)

I have to create "Init" method like this:

```
    public void Init(int deviceId)
    {
        _device = _deviceService.GetDeviceById(deviceId);
        // ...
    }
```

and add logic there.

Then I have to call `_service.Init(...);` before using _service methods. It works, but all disadvantages and potential problems are obviously (if forgot to call etc)

How to pass this parameter using DI ?

Comment: I have no answer to your question in terms of DI but
I solved a similar problem using an IHostedService to call the init() method. 
so in your case this would be a CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeServiceLuncher Service that calls the InitMethod of CreateAutoDeletingRequestReachSuspensionDaysLimitAndInactiveLongTimeService on startup. Maybe this works for your requirements too.

Comment: IMHO follow the "options pattern". Define a class with the data values. Add it as an `IOptions<>` dependency. Then either load that class from a settings file. Or write another service to populate values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-di-services-to-configure-options

Comment: Please check out my answer. If it doesn't answer your question, kindly provide comments, I'll update it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you'd like to define a `deviceId` during runtime based on the request?

Comment: Do you mind reviewing answers and mark the right answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

✅ You can do it with .NET 6 Dependency Injection like this.

First, create a .NET 6 Console App (with top-level statements) and add necessary NuGet packages.

Install NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, 6.0.0
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting, 6.0.0

---

1. Add usings:

   ```
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
   ```
2. Create a dependency that can be injected to our service and in other places:

   ```
   public class Dependency : IDependency
   {
       // Initialize Id with a random value to validate that it's the same instance for the same scope
       public Guid Id { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();
   }

   // Interface for DI
   public interface IDependency
   {
       public Guid Id { get; }
   }
   ```
3. Define our service with custom ID per scope:

   ```
   public class RequestService : IRequestService
   {
       public IDependency Dependency { get; init; }

       private int _id;

       // Constructor is used for standard dependency injection
       public RequestService(IDependency dependency)
       {
           Dependency = dependency;
       }

       // Init method is used to set custom ID via DI.
       public void Init(int id)
       {
           _id = id;
       }
   }

   public interface IRequestService
   {
       IDependency Dependency { get; }

       void Init(int id);
   }
   ```
4. Create a Host Builder:

   ```
   var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
   // You can do exactly the same with an `WebApplicationBuilder`
   // WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
   ```
5. Start configuring DI:

   ```
   builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
   {
       // Must be scoped
       services.AddScoped<IDependency, Dependency>();
       // Must be scoped
       services.AddScoped<IRequestService, RequestService>();

       // <Add a factory method DI configuration here>
   });
   ```

   5.1. Configure a factory to instantiate your service via DI and to set an arbitrary ID during that.

   **This is the main part of the DI magic**

   Factory function will do:

   - Take `int` id as an input.
   - Instantiate `IRequestService` via DI (essentially, will create a `RequestService` object).
   - Calls `.Init(id)` with ID value passed as an argument.

   ```
   // Add into `builder.ConfigureServices(services => {})`

   // Must be scoped
   services.AddScoped<Func<int, IRequestService>>(implementationFactory: provider =>
   {
       // Create a new factory
       return new Func<int, IRequestService>(id =>
       {
           var result = provider.GetRequiredService<IRequestService>();
           result.Init(id);
           return result;
       });
   });
   ```
6. After that just build the Host and create a DI scope:

   ```
   var host = builder.Build();

   var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
   ```
7. Finally, use the DI:

   ```
   // Resolve an `IDependency` just for the sake of the example
   var dependency = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDependency>();

   // Resolve a factory for your service
   var requestServiceFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Func<int, IRequestService>>();
   // Use a factory with custom ID
   var requestService = requestServiceFactory(32);
   ```

   Note: `dependency` and `requestService.Dependency` will be the same instance.

---

**So, if you inject `Func<int, IRequestService>` anywhere, you'll be able to instantiate your `IRequestService` using that factory with custom ID.**

You will never forget to call `.Init(id)` as it's required by the function signature and compiler will not allow you to skip it.

❗ If your service is disposable, you would have to take care of it yourself. DI will not help you with it.

⚠ *I use a Generic Host and Console App but it will work exactly in the same way in the Web API or ASP.NET MVC application.*

---

> Useful links:
>
> - [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution is really flexible! It's the same what I asked!

Comment: @OlegSh, happy to help. I really enjoy the beauty of .NET DI :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
serviceCollection
    .AddScoped<IYourService>(s => new YourService(
         s.GetService<YourPreviouslyInjectedService1>(),
         s.GetService<YourPreviouslyInjectedService2>(),
         s.GetService<YourPreviouslyInjectedService3>(),
         deviceId
    )
);
```

But I would advise against it and use `IOptions` with a configuration object injected like:

```
.Configure<YourConfigurationWithDeviceIdProperty>(
    c => builder.Configuration.GetSection("YourConfigSectionInAppSettings").Bind(c)
)
```

First, you are avoiding all this noise in the DI layer and second, you are making sure that you are injecting the correct setting as your constructor would accept a parameter of a specific type and not a primitive which can be anything ("123", "banana", etc).

Comment: No-no, `deviceId` is not a static field

Comment: Do you even understand what is dependency injection? If you need a dynamic value, simply add an additional parameter to your function. Why pollute the constructor for this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to do this is to not inject any primitive, but to instead inject a configuration class (`SomethingSomethingSettings`) that is unique to avoid collisions on parameter types, or to inject `IOptions<SomethingSomethingSettings>` to take advantage of .NET configuration support.

Another way to do this is to inject a factory class that can be used at runtime that has all the logic to do what you need. So instead of an `Init` method and a `_device` member, you would instead have a `_factory` member whose `Create` method would be invoked as needed, and with context it needs (again, typically from a `SomethingSomethingSettings` class.

Answer (score 1):

If your `deviceId` does not come from the application settings but it is a dynamic value during runtime then `Autofac` can help you.

```cs
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;

public class Service1
{
    public object GetById(int someId) { }
}

public class Service2 { }

public interface IMainService { }

public interface IMainServiceFactory
{
    IMainService Create(int someId);
}

public class MainService : IMainService
{
    private readonly object something;

    public MainService(Service1 service1, Service2 service2, int someId)
    {
        something = service1.GetById(someId);
    }
}

public class MainServiceFactory : IMainServiceFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope;

    public MainServiceFactory(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        this.lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();
    }

    public IMainService Create(int someId)
    {
        return lifetimeScope.Resolve<IMainService>(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                // Predicate for the .ctor parameter: int someId
                (parameter, context) =>
                    parameter.ParameterType == typeof(int)
                    &&
                    parameter.Name == nameof(someId)

                // The resolved value for the .ctor parameter.
                (parameter, context) => someId
            )
        );
    }
}
```

To integrate `Autofac` with the built-in MS DI you can use the [Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection) nuget package.

In .NET 6 you can do the following:

```cs
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder
    .Host
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

builder
    .Services
    .AddScoped<Service1>()
    .AddScoped<Service2>()
    .AddScoped<IMainService, MainService>()
    .AddScoped<IMainServiceFactory, MainServiceFactory>();

// Inject the IMainServiceFactory where you need the resolve an instance of IMainService
IMainService mainService = mainServiceFactory.Create(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Singleton, Scoped, Transient...
services.AddSinleton<IYourInterface, YourClass>();
services.AddSinleton<IYourInterface2, YourClass2>();
```

then you can use any class ctor

```
private readonly IYourInterfaceService _yourInterfaceService;
private readonly IYourInterfaceService2 _yourInterfaceService2;

public PersonExpenseController(IYourInterfaceService yourInterfaceService, IYourInterfaceService2 yourInterfaceService2)
{
    _yourInterfaceService = yourInterfaceService;
    _yourInterfaceService2 = yourInterfaceService2
}
```

}